# call function without parenthesis

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is confusing me, i am trying to create an identifier like Jquery.

```
$.ajax
$('object')
```

the jquery identifier `$` can be called without its parenthesis.

Here is some code i got:

```
function initialized_object(){
    this.method = function(){
        console.log('this is a string');
    }
}
var o = function (args){
    if(arguments.length > 0){
        //return N$(arguments[0], arguments[1]);
    }else{
        return new initialized_object();
    }
};
o.prototype.constructor.toString = function(){
    this.call(this);
}
o().method();
```

> Instead of `o().method()` i would like to use `o.method()`

I looked at the jquery source in attempt to find the solution to this with no avail: http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js

---

### This is what i am working with:

( in case you have any ideas )

```
function N$_no_parameters(){
    this.ajax = function(func){
        func();
    };
};
var N$_np = new N$_no_parameters();

var N$_CURRENT_EVENT_THIS = null;
function N$(selector, within){
    this.co = "hi";
    if (!Array.prototype.indexOf){
        Array.prototype.indexOf = function(elt /*, from*/){
            var len = this.length >>> 0;
            var from = Number(arguments[1]) || 0;
            from = (from < 0) ? Math.ceil(from) : Math.floor(from);
            if (from < 0)
                from += len;
            for (; from < len; from++){
                if (from in this && this[from] === elt)
                    return from;
            }
            return -1;
        };
    }
    var DOM_N$ = function(selector, within, frame){
        this.frame = frame || {
            win: (within != undefined)? within.contentWindow || this.constructor.caller.arguments[0] : this.constructor.caller.arguments[0],
            doc: (within != undefined)? within.contentDocument || this.constructor.caller.arguments[0].document : this.constructor.caller.arguments[0].document,
            this: this.constructor.caller.caller.caller.caller.caller
        };

        if(selector instanceof Object){
            if(selector.defaultView == this.frame.win){//selector is document
                this.selector = selector;
                this.nodes = [this.selector];
            }else if(selector.document == document){//selector is window
                this.selector = selector;
                this.nodes = [this.selector];
            }else if(selector instanceof this.frame.this){// selector is this
                this.selector = N$_CURRENT_EVENT_THIS.selector;
                this.nodes = N$_CURRENT_EVENT_THIS.nodes;//
            }else if(selector instanceof Element){//selector is DOM
                this.selector = selector;
                this.nodes = [this.selector];
            }else{
                this.selector = selector;
                this.nodes = new Array();
                for(var key in selector){
                    var dom_n$_ = N$(selector[key]).nodes;
                    for(var key_ in dom_n$_){
                        if(this.nodes.indexOf(dom_n$_[key_]) == -1){
                            this.nodes.push(dom_n$_[key_]);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }else if(typeof selector == "string"){
            this.selector = selector;
            this.nodes = $prepare(this.selector, this.frame.doc);
        }
        this.event = function(event_, func){
            var that = this;
            actionair(function(node){
                var events = node.events || {};
                if(node.addEventListener){
                    if((event_) in events){
                        node.removeEventListener(event_, events[event_], true);
                        var tmp___ = events[event_];
                        var tmp__ = function(){
                            this.bar = "hello";
                            N$_CURRENT_EVENT_THIS = that;
                            tmp___(node, event_);
                            new func(node, event_);
                            N$_CURRENT_EVENT_THIS = null;
                        };
                        node.addEventListener(event_, tmp__, true);
                        events[event_] = tmp__;
                    }else{
                        var tmp__ = function(){
                            N$_CURRENT_EVENT_THIS = that;
                            new func(node, event_);
                            N$_CURRENT_EVENT_THIS = null;
                        };
                        node.addEventListener(event_, tmp__, true);
                        events[event_] = tmp__;
                    }
                }else if(node.attachEvent){
                    var ie_event = 'on' + event_;
                    if(event_ in events){
                        node.attachEvent(ie_event, function(){
                            N$_CURRENT_EVENT_THIS = that;
                            new func(node, event_);
                            events[event_](node, event_);
                            N$_CURRENT_EVENT_THIS = null;
                        });
                    }else{
                        node.attachEvent(ie_event, function(){
                            N$_CURRENT_EVENT_THIS = that;
                            new func(node, event_);
                            N$_CURRENT_EVENT_THIS = null;
                        });
                    }
                    events[event_] = func;
                }
                node.events = events;

            }, this);
        }

        this.removeEvent = function(event_){
            actionair(function(node, that){
                var events = node.events || {};
                if(node.removeEventListener){
                    if((event_) in events){
                        node.removeEventListener(event_, events[event_], true);
                        events[event_] = null;
                    }
                }else if(node.detachEvent){
                    var ie_event = 'on' + event_;
                    if((event_) in events){
                        node.detachEvent(ie_event, events[event_]);
                        delete events[event_];
                    }
                }
            }, this);
        }
        this.eachNode = function(func){
            actionair(function(node, that){
                N$_CURRENT_EVENT_THIS = N$(node);
                new func(node);
            }, this);
        }
        this.css = function(attr, value){
            N$_CURRENT_EVENT_THIS = this;
            var attribute = "";
            if(attr.indexOf('-') !== -1){
                var split_attr = attr.split('-');
                for (var i = 0; i < split_attr.length; i++) {
                    if(i != 0)
                        attribute += split_attr[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + split_attr[i].slice(1);
                    else
                        attribute += split_attr[i].charAt(0).toLowerCase() + split_attr[i].slice(1);
                };
            }else{
                attribute = attr;
            }

            var properties = new Array();


            actionair(function(node, that){
                if(typeof value != 'undefined'){
                    node.style[attribute] = value;
                }
                if (!that.frame.win.getComputedStyle) {//IE
                    that.frame.win.getComputedStyle = function(el, pseudo) {
                        that.el = el;
                        that.getPropertyValue = function(prop) {
                            var re = /(\-([a-z]){1})/g;
                            if (prop == 'float') prop = 'styleFloat';
                            if (re.test(prop)) {
                                prop = prop.replace(re, function () {
                                    return arguments[2].toUpperCase();
                                });
                            }
                            return el.currentStyle[prop] ? el.currentStyle[prop] : null;
                        }
                        return that;
                    }
                }
                properties.push(that.frame.win.getComputedStyle(node, null).getPropertyValue(attr));

            }, this);
            return properties;
        };

        this.text = function(str){
            actionair(function(node, that){
                node.innerHTML = '';
                node.appendChild(that.frame.doc.createTextNode(str));
            }, this);
        };
        this.appendNode = function(tagname, innerHTML){
            actionair(function(node, that){
                var new_node = that.frame.doc.createElement(tagname);
                new_node.innerHTML = innerHTML;
                node.appendChild(new_node);

            }, this);
        };
        this.innerHTML = function(innerHTML){
            actionair(function(node, that){
                node.innerHTML = innerHTML;
            }, this);
        };
        this.removeNode = function(){
            actionair(function(node, that){
                node.parentNode.removeChild(node);
            }, this);
        };
        this.animate = function(func, from, to, speed){

            var that = this;
            actionair(function(node, that){
                (function animate(func, from, to, speed, node){
                    if(from >= to){
                        N$_CURRENT_EVENT_THIS = that;
                        new func(node, to);
                        N$_CURRENT_EVENT_THIS = null;
                    }else{
                        N$_CURRENT_EVENT_THIS = that;
                        new func(node, from);
                        N$_CURRENT_EVENT_THIS = null;
                        setTimeout(
                            function(){
                                animate(func, from+1, to, speed, node);
                            }, speed
                        );
                    }
                })(func, from, to, speed, node);
            }, this);
        }

        function actionair(func, that){
            for (var i = 0; i < that.nodes.length; i++) {
                (function(i_){
                    N$_CURRENT_EVENT_THIS = that;
                    new func(that.nodes[i_], that);
                    N$_CURRENT_EVENT_THIS = null;
                })(i);
            }
        }
        function $prepare(str, doc){
            str = str.replace(/(\s+>\s+)/g,'>');
            str = str.replace(/(\s+)/g,' ');
            var str_ = str;
            var querys = str.split(/[\s\>]+/);
            var querys_des = Array();

            var ascender = new Array();
            for (var i = 0; i < str_.length; i++) {
                if(str_[i] == ">" || str_[i] == " "){
                    var tmp_ = (str_[i] == ">")? 'next_child' : 'ascended';
                    ascender.push( tmp_);
                }
            };
            var recognizes = new Array();
            for (var i = 0; i < querys.length; i++) {
                var asc_child = null;
                asc_child = ascender[i-1];
                var tmp_ = {
                    "selector": querys[i],
                    "i":i
                };
                recognizes[i] = recognize(querys[i], doc);
                if(i != 0){
                    tmp_["asc_child"] = asc_child;
                }else{
                    tmp_["base_selector"] = true;
                }
                querys_des.push(tmp_);
            };
            return $select(querys_des, recognizes, doc);
        }
        function $select(querys_des, recognizes, parent_, doc){
            var parents = parent_ || null;
            for (var i = 0; i < querys_des.length; i++) {
                if('base_selector' in querys_des[i]){
                    parents = recognizes[querys_des[i]['i']];
                }else if('asc_child' in querys_des[i]){
                    var cur_children = recognizes[querys_des[i]['i']];
                    if(querys_des[i]['asc_child'] == 'next_child'){
                        var compatible = compatible_children(parents, cur_children, querys_des[i]['asc_child'], doc);
                        parents = compatible;
                    }else if(querys_des[i]['asc_child'] == 'ascended'){
                        var compatible = compatible_children(parents, cur_children, querys_des[i]['asc_child'], doc);
                        parents = compatible;
                    }
                }
            };

            return parents;
        }

        function compatible_children(parents, children, type, doc){
            var ret = new Array();
            for (var a = 0; a < parents.length; a++) {
                for (var b = 0; b < children.length; b++) {
                    if(type == 'next_child'){
                        if(parents[a] == children[b].parentNode){
                            if(ret.indexOf(children[b]) == -1)
                                ret.push(children[b]);
                        }
                    }else if(type == 'ascended'){
                        if(isin(parents[a], children[b], doc)){
                            if(ret.indexOf(children[b]) == -1)
                                ret.push(children[b]);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return ret;
        }

        function isin(parent, child, doc){
            var child_ = child;
            var ret = new Array();
            while((child_ = child_.parentNode) && child_ != doc.body){
                if(parent == child_){
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }

        function recognize(str, doc){
            var identifier = new Array();

            var id_ = false;
            var class_ = false;
            var dom_ = false;
            if(str.indexOf("#") >= 0){
                id_ = true;
                var tmp = str.split("#")[1];
                if(str.indexOf(".") >= 0){
                    identifier['ID'] = tmp.split(".")[0];
                }else{
                    identifier['ID'] = tmp;
                }
            }

            if(str.indexOf(".") >= 0){
                class_ = true;
                var tmp = str.split(".")[1];
                if(str.indexOf("#") >= 0){
                    identifier['CLASS'] = tmp.split("#")[0];
                }else{
                    identifier['CLASS'] = tmp;
                }
            }


            if(id_ && class_){
                if(str.indexOf("#") < str.indexOf(".")){
                    var tmp = str.split("#")[0];
                    if(tmp.length > 0){
                        dom_ = true;
                        identifier['DOM'] = tmp;
                    }
                }else{
                    var tmp = str.split(".")[0];
                    if(tmp.length > 0){
                        dom_ = true;
                        identifier['DOM'] = tmp;
                    }
                }
            }else if(id_){
                var tmp = str.split("#")[0];
                if(tmp.length > 0){
                    dom_ = true;
                    identifier['DOM'] = tmp;
                }
            }else if(class_){
                var tmp = str.split(".")[0];
                if(tmp.length > 0){
                    dom_ = true;
                    identifier['DOM'] = tmp;
                }
            }else{
                if(str.length > 0){
                    dom_ = true;
                    identifier['DOM'] = str;
                }
            }


            var x;
            if(class_){
                if(typeof doc.getElementsByClassName !== 'function') {//Old browsers
                    x = doc.body.getElementsByTagName("*");
                }else{
                    x = doc.getElementsByClassName(identifier['CLASS']);
                }

            }else if(dom_){
                x = doc.getElementsByTagName(identifier['DOM']);
            }else if(id_){
                x = doc.body.getElementsByTagName("*");
                for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
                    if(x[i].getAttribute("id") != identifier['ID']){
                        delete x[i];
                    }
                };
            }

            var elements = new Array();


            for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
                if(id_ && class_){
                    if(x[i].getAttribute("id") == identifier["ID"] && x[i].getAttribute("class") == identifier["CLASS"]){
                        if(dom_){
                            if(x[i].tagName.toLowerCase() == identifier['DOM'].toLowerCase()){
                                elements.push(x[i]);
                            }
                        }else{
                            elements.push(x[i]);
                        }
                    }
                }else if(id_){
                    if(x[i].getAttribute("id") == identifier["ID"]){
                        if(dom_){
                            if(x[i].tagName.toLowerCase() == identifier['DOM'].toLowerCase()){
                                elements.push(x[i]);
                            }
                        }else{
                            elements.push(x[i]);
                        }
                    }
                }else if(class_){
                    if(x[i].getAttribute("class") == identifier["CLASS"]){
                        if(dom_){
                            if(x[i].tagName.toLowerCase() == identifier['DOM'].toLowerCase()){
                                elements.push(x[i]);
                            }
                        }else{
                            elements.push(x[i]);
                        }
                    }
                }else{
                    if(dom_){
                        if(x[i].tagName.toLowerCase() == identifier['DOM'].toLowerCase()){
                            elements.push(x[i]);
                        }
                    }else{
                        elements.push(x[i]);
                    }
                }

            };

            return elements;
        }
    };

    var selectors = new Array();
    console.log('arguments' + arguments.length);
    if(arguments.length > 0){
        return new (function(selector, within){
            if(typeof within == typeof {}){
                if(within.nodes != undefined){
                    var ret = new Array();
                    for (var i = within.nodes.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                        ret.push(do_node_select(selector, within.nodes[i]));
                    };
                    return ret;
                }else if(
                    typeof Node === "object" ? within instanceof Node : 
                    within && typeof within === "object" && typeof within.nodeType === "number" && typeof within.nodeName==="string"
                ){
                    return do_node_select(selector, within);
                }
            }
            return do_node_select(selector, undefined);

            function do_node_select(selector, node){


                    var N$_new = new ( function(win, doc){
                        return new DOM_N$(selector, node || undefined);
                    })(window);

                    var N$_ = null;
                    if(selectors.length > 0){
                        for (var i = selectors.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                            if(selectors[i].selector == selector){
                                var not_in = new Array();
                                for (var b = N$_new.nodes.length - 1; b >= 0; b--) {
                                    if(selectors[i].nodes.indexOf(N$_new.nodes[b]) == -1){
                                        not_in.push(N$_new.nodes[b]);
                                    }
                                };
                                for (var a = not_in.length - 1; a >= 0; a--) {
                                    if(selectors[i].nodes.indexOf(not_in[a]) == -1){
                                        selectors[i].nodes.push(not_in[a]);
                                    }
                                };
                                N$_ = selectors[i];
                                break;
                            }else{
                                N$_ = N$_new;
                            }
                        };
                    }else{
                        N$_ = N$_new;
                        if(N$_.nodes.length > 0){
                            selectors.push(N$_);
                        }
                    }
                    return N$_;

            }
        })(selector, within || undefined);
    }else{
        return N$_np;
    }

};


N$(window).event('load', function(){

    N$.ajax(function(){ // this will not work but using N$().ajax will
        console.log('aaa');
    });
});
```

This is a library i am making similar to Jquery, it selects nodes & handles events and more. the reason i would like to call my ajax function without parenthesis is for clarity.

Comment: What happens if you do `var o = new initialized_object();`? Then does it work?

Comment: How else do you want to use `o` ? By the way, your `toString` method is really weird, not sure what the value is of doing `o.prototype.constructor.toString`

Comment: o.prototype.constructor.toString calls the object when the object.toString is called so essentially just using o would call the object. but this doesnt work.

Comment: @musefan yes that works, but o can return 2 different objects, unless i had 2 different identifies that wouldn't work for me. But i am considering it.

Comment: Im going to post up the code im working with, maybe someone can give some tips.

Comment: Tip: It's usually not a good idea to stick a huge uncommented code dump in your question. This isn't [codereview.SE] (and if you did post your code there, the first thing they'd call you on would be the lack of comments and general readability).

Comment: @IlmariKaronen tip: code dumps are bad, *especially* on Code Review, where context is utterly important.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen The code dump is only EXTRA information, The code speaks for itself. There's no need for comments. You can easily see how the object is being initialized. Again its only for EXTRA information.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

> the jquery identifier $ can be called without its parenthesis.

No. The function isn't being called.

Functions are objects. Objects can have properties. This is simply accessing a property of the function object.

```js
function foo() {
  return 1;
}

foo.bar = 2;

alert(foo.bar);
alert(foo());
```

> Instead of o().method() i would like to use o.method()

Those statements mean different things.

The first calls the method method of the value that is *returned when you call the o function*.

The second calls the method method of the *o function* itself.

The second doesn't touch the initialised object (or even create one) at all.

Comment: This is one of the solutions i came up with before posting this question, which i was hoping to avoid using. This method does work though, so i commend that.

Comment: @Richard: This is *the* way to do it, and precisely the way jQuery does it (except that they use the [`jQuery.extend()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/) helper method to set most of the properties, but this is what the `.extend()` method does internally).

Comment: @Richard If you don't believe it, please read through the source code for [jQuery](https://robflaherty.github.io/jquery-annotated-source/docs/01-core.html), [Underscore](http://underscorejs.org/docs/underscore.html), etc. It's all done using this method.

Answer (score 7):

$ is a function. But functions in JavaScript are also objects, which in-turn can have functions.

Perhaps this pattern is closer to what you are looking for:

```
var o = {
    method: function() {
    }
};
o.method();
```

Comment: `$` is also a function

Comment: Thanks @JuanMendes I updated my answer to make it more clear with regards to your comment

Answer (score 2):

Every time you call `o()` you get a new instance that can behave differently based on how you call it.

If you were to just call `o.method`, how would it know which reference to use? To be like jQuery,  you would do

```
o = o() // or o('something')
```

which would create a global singleton `o` that you could then call `o.method`.

Comment: but how can i use the variable o and the object o with parameters?

Comment: @RichardGrant Not sure what you are asking

Answer (score 1):

Quentim's answer is completely correct. You're just acessing a property, no big deal. I just wanted to add that there's a way to "call a function without parenthesis" if you're using [getters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get):

```
window.__defineGetter__("$", function() { 
    //This gets executed when you access $
    console.log('oh hai'); 
    return { foo: 'bar' } 
});
```

Not that this should be done at all, but this is a way of achieving what's in the question title